# Use property type in expression

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, lambda, types, expression-trees

I have a function which creates a different type of expression depending on the value of the variable passed in.

```
Protected Function BuildSortPredicate(ByVal tableType As Object, ByRef expr As Expression)
    Dim sortExpression As Expression
    If tableType Is "Job" Then
        sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of Job, String))(expr)
    ElseIf tableType Is "User" Then
        sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of User, Integer))(expr)
    ...
    End If
    Return sortExpression
End Function
```

How can I avoid the lengthy if/else (or case switch) structure?
Ideally, I'm looking for something like this:

```
Protected Function BuildSortPredicate(ByVal tableType As Object, ByRef exprt As Expression)
    Dim sortExpression As Expression
    sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of tableType, String))(expr)
    Return sortExpression
End Function
```

The overall goal here is to convert the expression to the appropriate type so that I can use it in my LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a Generic function

```
Protected Function BuildSortPredicate(Of T)(ByVal expr As Expression) As Expression
    Dim sortExpression As Expression
    sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, String))(expr)
    Return sortExpression
End Function
```